# How to add Hrs./Day and Avg Hrs./Week in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My sheet looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZDNU.png)

.csv code:

```
Date,Project name,Minutes spent,Time Start,Time End,Day
09/09/2022,Tast I,120,11:30 AM,1:30 PM,Friday
09/09/2022,Tast II,120,1:30 PM,3:30 PM,Friday
09/09/2022,Tast II,90,3:30 PM,5:00 PM,Friday
09/09/2022,Tast II,120,6:30 PM,8:30 PM,Friday
10/09/2022,Tast III,120,8:30 AM,10:30 AM,Saturday
10/09/2022,Tast III,120,10:30 AM,12:30 PM,Saturday
10/09/2022,Tast III,120,12:30 PM,2:30 PM,Saturday
10/09/2022,Tast III,150,2:30 PM,5:00 PM,Saturday
10/09/2022,Tast III,210,6:30 PM,10:00 PM,Saturday
11/09/2022,,,,,Sunday
12/09/2022,Tast IV,120,8:30 AM,10:30 AM,Monday
12/09/2022,Tast IV,90,10:30 AM,12:00 PM,Monday
12/09/2022,Tast V,120,12:00 PM,2:00 PM,Monday
12/09/2022,Tast V,180,2:00 PM,5:00 PM,Monday
```

I want to add these two more columns showing hrs/day and total hours/week (including Sundays, I sometimes have to work on those):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIHtE.png)

.csv code:

```
Date,Project name,Minutes spent,Time Start,Time End,Day,Hrs./Day,Total Hrs./ Week
09/09/2022,Tast I,120,11:30 AM,1:30 PM,Friday,7.5,19.5
09/09/2022,Tast II,120,1:30 PM,3:30 PM,Friday,7.5,19.5
09/09/2022,Tast II,90,3:30 PM,5:00 PM,Friday,7.5,19.5
09/09/2022,Tast II,120,6:30 PM,8:30 PM,Friday,7.5,19.5
10/09/2022,Tast III,120,8:30 AM,10:30 AM,Saturday,12,19.5
10/09/2022,Tast III,120,10:30 AM,12:30 PM,Saturday,12,19.5
10/09/2022,Tast III,120,12:30 PM,2:30 PM,Saturday,12,19.5
10/09/2022,Tast III,150,2:30 PM,5:00 PM,Saturday,12,19.5
10/09/2022,Tast III,210,6:30 PM,10:00 PM,Saturday,12,19.5
11/09/2022,,,,,Sunday,0,8.5
12/09/2022,Tast IV,120,8:30 AM,10:30 AM,Monday,8.5,8.5
12/09/2022,Tast IV,90,10:30 AM,12:00 PM,Monday,8.5,8.5
12/09/2022,Tast V,120,12:00 PM,2:00 PM,Monday,8.5,8.5
12/09/2022,Tast V,180,2:00 PM,5:00 PM,Monday,8.5,8.5
```

I'm new to this and looks like I can't post images yet. Please use the .csv file to help. Thanks.

Edit: Tast = Task.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a copy of your spreadsheet, free of sensitive information, so we can look at the exact structure of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Hrs./Day` column.

```
=BYROW(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),LAMBDA(x,SUM(FILTER(INDEX((E2:E-D2:D)*24),A2:A=x))))
```

For `Total Hrs./ Week` column.

```
=BYROW(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),LAMBDA(x,SUM(FILTER(INDEX((E2:E-D2:D)*24),INDEX(WEEKNUM(A2:A))=WEEKNUM(x)))))
```